# Pass object to modal when it shows up

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple table with avability to edit particular row's item. When user clicks icon (with class `icon ion-md-create`) modal shows up, and then user can edit data. Modal contains form, so when user submits form, the controller is updating the database with new data.

This is how I display rows:

```
@foreach (var measurement in Model.WeightMeasurements)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => measurement.MeasurementDate)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => measurement.Value)</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn-icon" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWeight" data-id="@measurement.Id" data-weight="@measurement.Value" data-date="@measurement.MeasurementDate"> 
                <i class="icon ion-md-create"></i> 
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is how I get each row data and insert them into modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editWeight').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // get data
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        var weight = $(e.relatedTarget).data('weight');
        var date = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');

        // insert data in modal
        $('#e_weight_id').val(id);
        $('#e_weight_value').val(weight);
        $('#e_datepickerWeight').val(date);
    });
});
```

This is how my modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal animated bounceIn" id="editWeight" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditWeightMeasurement", "Measurement", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pt-5" }))
                    {
                        @Html.Hidden("e_weight_id", "");
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 form-group">
                                <label for="uname">Weight [kg] </label>
                                @Html.TextBox("e_weight_value", "", new { @placeholder = "Edit weight", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Date</label>
                                    @Html.TextBox("e_weight_date", "", new { @id = "e_datepickerWeight", @class = "form -control datepicker" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex py-3 align-items-center">
                            <div class="ml-auto">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn pink">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't like the way how js works there - Instead of getting the data from `html` I would like to pass whole `measurement` object into `modal` (the same way how object is passed from `form` to `controller` layer). Is this possible to do?

Comment: please share your code if possible, so I can help to improve from scratch
DM code

Comment: @HardikMasalawala I already added code

Comment: Share on mail from my profile if possible

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use event.relatedTarget and HTML data-* attributes in modal bootstrap 4

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> You can also visit this [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) for more information

Comment: Hi @miladnematzadeh, usually when referencing documentation we like to quote it in the answer. That way if the URL ever changes, the answer is still usable by people searching in the future. Could you edit your answer to point out which parts of the docs you're referring to specifically?